# Angular unit test: value returned by service function

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test for angular app, I am testing service. Test fails when I expect value returned by service function equal to 'king'.

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class TopToolBarService {

 customer = null;
 getCustomer() {
    return this.customer;
  }
}
```

**test.spec.js**

```
it ('should check return value of service',() = > {
 let service:TopToolBarService
 const valueServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('TopToolBarService', ['getCustomer']);
 valueServiceSpy.and.returnValue("king");
 var result = component.getCustomer();
 expect (result).toBe("king");
//test failed, value of result is null

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs a return value on the function, not the whole object, try this:

```
it ('should check return value of service', () => {
 let mockTopToolBarService: jasmine.SpyObj<TopToolBarService>;
 mockTopToolBarService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TopToolBarService', ['getCustomer']);
 mockTopToolBarService.getCustomer.and.returnValue("king");

 var result = component.getCustomer();
 expect(result).toBe("king");
});
```

Note that `service` points to an object with a spy named `getCustomer` - I updated the `it` to better illustrate what is happening.

Another thing you will need to consider is that the TopToolBarService is probably getting mocked too late in the spec. I typically mock them at the top like so:

```
describe('Component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    let mockTopToolBarService: jasmine.SpyObj<TopToolBarService>;
    mockTopToolBarService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TopToolBarService', ['getCustomer']);
    mockTopToolBarService.getCustomer.and.returnValue("king");

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component],
      providers: [{ provide: TopToolBarService, useValue: mockTopToolBarService}]
    });

    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it ('should check return value of service', () => {
    var result = component.getCustomer();
    expect(result).toBe("king");
  });
});
```

When you define your mocked service at the top of the spec like this, it is injected into your spec and your mock is used instead of the real service.